# Access - open Excel file, do some coding with It and close

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to open an Excel file from Access and do some stuff with It, but code is not stable. Sometimes It works, other times not. Here's how I do this:

```
 Dim FilePath As String
 Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application

 FilePath = "C:\Users\Lucky\Desktop\Test.xls"

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open (FilePath)

With ExcelApp

'do some stuff here
End With

ExcelApp.Workbooks.Close

Set ExcelApp = Nothing
```

I've also noticed that once I run code, Excel starts proccess under Task Manager, that has to be killed manually in order to get code working again. Otherwise I get two types of error with Excel file:

- one is that If I click Excel file, It doesn't open, It just flashes for a second and dissapears
- and other is that Excel file opens in "read-only" mode...

So I reckon there is some flaw when file is closed in my code. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem. There is nothing wrong with code in my question, except that instead of declaring

```
Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
```

It's better to use

```
Dim ExcelApp As Object
```

But much bigger problem is with code that does changes in Excel, such as this line:

```
x = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Value
```

And correct synthax is:

```
x = ExcelApp.Range(ExcelApp.Cells(1, i), ExcelApp.Cells(ExcelApp.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Value 'maybe also better to replace xlUp with -4162
```

So, whenever you use some code for Excel file from Access, DON'T FORGET to reference everything to Excel object. And ofcourse, before everything, a proper reference must be set in VBA console, in my case Microsoft Office 15.0 library.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what's wrong with your code - maybe the path to the desktop?
This is the code I usually use - I've added another function to help choose the file.  It uses late binding, so no need to set a reference to Excel - you don't get the IntelliSense and can't use Excel constants such as `xlUp` - you have to use the numerical equivalent.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim oXLApp As Object
    Dim oXLWrkBk As Object
    Dim oXLWrkSht As Object
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    vFile = GetFile()

    Set oXLApp = CreateXL
    Set oXLWrkBk = oXLApp.WorkBooks.Open(vFile, False)
    Set oXLWrkSht = oXLWrkBk.WorkSheets(1) 'First sheet.  Can also use "Sheet1", etc...

    lLastRow = oXLWrkSht.Cells(oXLWrkSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(-4162).Row '-4162 = xlUp

    MsgBox "Last row in column A is " & lLastRow

    oXLWrkBk.Close False
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLWrkBk = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing


End Sub

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function

Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1, Optional sFilterName As String = "") As Variant
    Dim fle As Object
    Dim vItem As Variant

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Clear the file filter and add a new one. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Application.FileDialog(3).Filters.Clear
    Application.FileDialog(3).Filters.Add "'Some File Description' Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm"

    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(3)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a file"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for provided code, It's great and It works. However, the stuff I had to do with Excel file is causing me problems. I'll have to figure out something. And unfortunatelly, "Xlup" is something I need in code, and because of that I have problems too.

Comment: My biggest problem is this line - "i = Rows(1).Find("MyColumnName", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole).Column"...I get error 462 with this, "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". Any idea how to change this line ?

Comment: To find the value of an Excel constant open the Immediate window in Excel and type the constant in - `?xlUp` will return -4162

Comment: Darren, I allready posted my answer. I know about xlUp constant value.Thanks for all your help !!